# CASE Expression in JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, kotlin, dsl, jooq

How do I write the following SQL in JOOQ?

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN (in_kind OR goods) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS alt_donation
FROM donation
```

All the three columns (‘not_found’, ‘in_kind’ and ‘goods’) are boolean.

I have looked at other related questions and [JOOQ CASE Documentation](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/case-expressions/) and can make the following sql work in JOOQ.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN (not_found) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS alt_donation
FROM donation
```

The JOOQ version runs correctly for this example:

```kotlin
val query = dslContext
    .select(DSL.count().`as`("donations"),
            DSL.sum(DSL.choose(DONATION.NOT_FOUND).`when`(true, 0).otherwise(1)).`as`("altdonation"))
    .from(DONATION)
```

I need to use the earlier sql statement that uses an 'or' in CASE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use the [`FILTER (WHERE ..)` clause](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/), which is supported by jOOQ and emulated in SQL dialects that don't natively support it, in a similar way as yours:

#### In SQL

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, 
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE in_kind OR goods) AS alt_donation
FROM donation
```

#### In jOOQ

```java
ctx.select(count().`as`("donations"),
           count().filterWhere(condition(DONATION.IN_KIND)
                           .or(condition(DONATION.GOODS))).`as`("alt_donation"))
   .from(DONATION)
   .fetch();
```

Notice I'm turning a `Field<Boolean>` into a `Condition` using [`DSL.condition(Field<Boolean>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#condition-org.jooq.Field-), which is probably the API you were looking for

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Also, thank you for the SQL correction. Using FILTER is much cleaner than using CASE.